# Not able to extract a zipped file larger than 4 gb using zip archive ios

Tags: objective-c

I am using zipArchive sdk to unzip files. But the UnzipOpenFile call fails on files larger than 4gb. Please help.

Comment: Does zipArchive support the zip64 format?   That'd be required for 4GB+ files.

Comment: Are you kidding? Unzip 4gb on iOS device, crazy

Comment: Also depends on the type of Hard Drive it does not support files bigger than 4Gb....

Comment: HFS+ (and HFSX) volume format in iOS supports a max file size of 8 EB (8 million TB)...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and trying to solve it over couple of days.
Finally, i solved it.

With my instruction you can unzip big files (even 8GB) in iOS without any problems.

This is an step-by-step instruction how to solve it:

1) Download Objective-Zip from https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip

2) Download MiniZip from https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip

3) Take 4 files - ioapi.c, ioapi.h, unzip.c, unzip.h -  from minizip folder (which you downloaded in step 2) and paste it to the Objective-Zip/MiniZip folder (override files).

4) Go to Objective-Zip/Objective-Zip/ZipFile.m and replace this string

```
int err= unzLocateFile(_unzFile, [fileNameInZip cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 1);
```

to this

```
int err= unzLocateFile(_unzFile, [fileNameInZip cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], (unzFileNameComparer)1);
```

5) Finally, add Objective-Zip to your project and happy unzipping! :)

Now you can unzip big files in iOS. I checked on 8GB-zip, everything works like a charm!

P.S.: developer of Objective-Zip will update it with my fix as soon as possible, so this instruction is actual for Objective-Zip 0.8.1 only.